# First facebook-app: Hosting and Framework suggestions

Tags: facebook

I'm planning to do my first facebook-app. 
The core of the app would be to choose certain photos from your profile and show them to others users (of the same app). My background is more on the C++ side and low-level programming.

I want to know your suggestions for the following:

**1-** Which hosting do you suggest? I have read about google-app-engine and Heroku, however I am not sure which one fits best for a free plan until it grows to a significant number of users. 
Heroku seems great for a beginner since they give you a sample code, but I am not sure about their databases and their scalability while being free. From [here](http://www.heroku.com/pricing#0-0) I understand that I have only 5 mb of databases for free which seems too little... right?. 
And one more thing: I'm assuming is possible to show photos from others users directly from facebook without hosting it

**2-** Which framework and language do you suggest given the core of my app? It is not a sophisticated app, so I want to do it as fast as I can without many technical troubles.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Heroku is good choice for you. http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. So you think 5 mb is enough? What about a framework? Which would you suggest?

Comment: I write my own, but usually I suggest that, try to solve a problem - for example post on the wall -, and you will find the best for you. 5MB sorce is fair enough I think.